# Text right in the center

Tags: css, text, background

I'd like to have a text inside of a specific area (just middle of the screen), I made own background image in Paint and i want to have a paragraph (quote) inside of it. But however I am  trying, it just doesnt fit in my handmade background.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>     
   <style>
   body {
   margin:0;
   background-image: url('pozadi.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}  

h1 {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
li {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7092be;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
}
.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;

}
</style>

    <title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='author' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='all'>

  </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>

    <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
  <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
  <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
  <li><a href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
  <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>
</ul>

        <p class="p" align="center">“According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyways. Because bees don't care what humans think is impossible.”</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's how I want it to look like. Thanks for your help, I am still a beginner!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBTjV.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
   body {
   margin:0;
   background-image: url('pozadi.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}  

h1 {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
li {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7092be;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
}
.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;

}
.mw1200{max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;}
.fw{width:100%;float:left;background:#fff;}
.paragraphbg{background:url(https://i.ibb.co/rZB3jCZ/star.png);}
.paragraphbg p{padding:10px 10%;font-size:28px;text-align:left;}
```

```html
        <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>

    <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
  <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
  <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
  <li><a href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
  <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="fw paragraphbg">
<div class="mw1200">
<div class="fw">
        <p class="p" align="center">“According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyways. Because bees don't care what humans think is impossible.”</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, this kinda helped me, but now it looks like this and other pages are like this. Any help? :(
https://imgur.com/a/qcn0xfQ
https://imgur.com/a/zSd0J10

Comment: .paragraphbg div element copy and use to other pages

Answer (score 0):

### Margin way:

You can use CSS property `width` with [viewport-relative unit `vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vw) 'so your content will size in function of the screen size) and the [CSS property margin with the value `auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values) :

> The browser selects a suitable margin to use. For example, in certain
>   cases this value can be used to center an element.

**In short:**

```
.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50vw; /* Added --- Setting the width of your p in % of the width of the screen */
    margin:auto; /* Added --- make margin-left & margin-right even resulting of centering your p */
}
```

```css
body {
   margin:0;
   background-image: url('pozadi.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50vw;
    margin:auto;
}  

h1 {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
li {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7092be;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
}
.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>  
    <title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='author' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='all'>
  </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>

    <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
  <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
  <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
  <li><a href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
  <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>
</ul>
<main>

        <p class="p">“According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyways. Because bees don't care what humans think is impossible.”</p>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Flexbox way:

Or you can use the CSS flexbox layout.

```
main{
  display:flex; /* Added --- making the container a flexbox */
  justify-content:center; /* Added --- centering its element(s) */
}

.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw; /* Added --- Setting the width of your p in % of the width of the screen */
}
```

```css
body {
   margin:0;
   background-image: url('pozadi.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

main{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.p {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
}  

h1 {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
li {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7092be;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
}
.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>  
    <title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='author' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='all'>
  </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>

    <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
  <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
  <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
  <li><a href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
  <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>
</ul>
<main>

        <p class="p">“According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyways. Because bees don't care what humans think is impossible.”</p>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```